# Website Security

Tags: php, security, authorization

I'm creating a website which some information strictly for member only. I'm thinking:

1. Store information into database such as mySQL, if the information is too big, like the books, is it good choice?

(I would like to store e-books for different member reading. Does mySQL can store each book in each cell? If so is it good choice? )

1. Create files in different directory, however some one still can access those files if they know the path?

Any suggestion?

Comment: You need to provide a LOT more detail to get meaningful answers

Comment: How much data are you storing that can't fit in mySQL tables?

Comment: Too big? MySQL can fit Elephants ... is your data bigger than an Elephant?

Comment: perhaps mySQL can handle that _big_ information of yours

Comment: @Moon: are you talking about Angola elephants or Crete elephants from the Pleistocene period?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elephant

Comment: I would like to store e-books for different member reading. Does mySQL can store each book in each cell? If so is it good choice?

Comment: @ChrisLively: [MySQL storing African Elephants](http://www.ensembl.org/Loxodonta_africana/Info/Index)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you would think the information is too big..

However, if you are talking about serving files then typically you don't provide direct access to them.  Instead you would have something like `getfile.php?id=x`

The getfile page would be responsible for testing that the user is indeed logged and has rights to that file.  If so then it would stream the file back to the browser.

If not it would redirect them to a login page, or something else that's suitable.

Comment: with some mod_rewrite added in the mix you have a solution...